# Reading a decimal number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the reason behind reading a decimal number such as 9.25 as nine  point two five and not nine point twenty five?

Comment: It is convention.

Comment: $1.25 < 1.7$ but if you say "one point twenty-five is smaller than one point seven" I think you are going to confuse many people.

Comment: For numbers with only two digits behind the decimal place I have heard things like $.39$ read as "point thirty-nine".  It is most common with $.25$ and $.75$ because those are so common as quarters and people recognize them as such.  I would discourage it for the reasons other people give, but it does happen.

Comment: @RossMillikan Great "point!"  No, I really do mean it!

Comment: What would be the corresponding alternative reading for $9.025$?

Comment: @Barry nine-point-zero-two-five?

Comment: But Ross has a great point about number with only two digits to the right of the decimal; perhaps it's because of the connection to values expressed in percentage.  Ninety-nine percent is point-ninety-nine. Who knows?

Comment: @amWhy, I meant the alternative corresponding to the read of 9.25 as "nine point twenty-five."

Comment: This question is not  mathematical question; it is about human speaking norms, which differ from language to language.  This is a question best answered by the empirical sciences.  And it is likely that there is not one correct answer.

Comment: @Barru Cipra I would read 9.025 as "nine-point-zero-twenty-five", I don't know if it's standard though.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually read numbers as you wish if it is not ambiguous, so just do what is more convenient for you. In my personal experience, it's common to read things like 0.25 , 0.75 or even 0.125 as "zero point one hundred twenty five". For bigger decimal parts I usually spell it digit by digit, but I don't think there is some kind of convention for this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a number with more digits after the "point", say $9.2543764$. It would be rather difficult to follow if one would call this "nine point two million five hundred forty three thousand ....". That's why there is the convention to do it differently.

Comment: While what you observe could be problematic, indeed, I doubt that it is for that reason only, that the convention arose.  And Ross Millikan made a great point below the question.  You answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way taught in elementary math class to read decimal numbers is not actually with the word "Point" and always ends with the place value of the last digit.
[Web link](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/decimals/read_write.html)
9.25 is read as "nine and twenty-five hundredths"
9.7 is read as "nine and seven tenths"
0.25 437 641 is read as "twenty-five million, four hundred thirty-seven thousand, six hundred forty-one hundred-millionths".

Of course, conventionally English speakers just read it by individual digits.

Comment: Well that's just stupid. "Zero point two five four three seven six four one" is better in every way. Did you just make it up?

Comment: why not google it, that is the convention way and taught in school

Comment: As such the post is about "reading a decimal" not money and not digits

Comment: Convention is what people do (now, in real-life), and usually not what we were taught as children.  We also learned that we should strive to write and speak in grammatically correct ways in our native tongues.  If you lived your life speaking or writing only as taught as a child, only communicating with  perfect spelling, pronunciation, and grammar, you're not going to be fully understood, and probably not have many friends, either!

Comment: @amWhy Fair enough, after actually googling the definition of convention, I agree that real life isn't always done as taught in school. That said maybe the topic does need to be more specific on what they want in terms of "reading" a decimal.

Comment: "Twenty-five million, four hundred thirty-seven thousand, six hundred forty-one hundred-millionths" is not taught anywhere is the world as the way to pronounce that decimal number. You have confused it with the _meaning_ of a decimal number. The _meaning_ of $0.29$ is twenty-nine hundredths, but it is _pronounced_ "zero point two nine". I hope that clears things up.

Comment: @TonyK I didn't know numbers had "meaning" first off, they do have value. Second you don't "pronounce" the Point in worldly numeric system nor do you mention a zero when the number is between 1 and -1. Since 0 was only invented a few hundred years ago mainly as a positional space filler. Really this is a community for Math; math is universal and doesn't alter (maybe it becomes invented) like language does over time. Anyways like Wikipedia says a decimal is a fractional representation so 0.29 = 29/100 hence reading it as twenty-nine hundredths

Comment: @amWhy Did you want to alter the topic? Did you want what to know how school teaches you to read a decimal, or how the majority read a decimal by digits? Easily by googling my answer is the shown to be the way taught in school links [link](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/decimals/read_write.html)
or even [link](http://www.themathpage.com/arith/decimals-2.htm)

Comment: @Edward give it up. The question is closed, already.

Comment: @amWhy If you have gotten what you needed fine, but I would clarify I see it as "On hold" and not closed. Which means if the question was improved to the satisfaction of those who put it on hold it would become active again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: *Ignores stubborn answerer*

Comment: @Edward The sources you are citing are written for children by educators who are concerned with a theory of how mathematics should be presented in a classroom. They are not evidence of how grown-up mathematicians, scientists, or engineers communicate. In fact, "thirty-eight thousandths" _is_ something a grownup would likely say, but someone who says "twenty-five million, four hundred thirty-seven thousand, six hundred forty-one hundred-millionths" is not communicating in a way designed to be understood correctly by other adults.

Comment: @DavidK which goes to what amWhy was referring to convention, and the fact the person who asked didn't specify in what context they where trying to "read" a decimal. As is normal in today's society we read numbers by digits, especially when talking to an automated system. But I did mention that it is also within Wikipedia how decimals are fractional representations, where you could then "read" the numerator like you would a whole number.

Comment: @Edward I think what earned you the critical comments and the downvotes is mainly the way you designated a certain grade-school convention as "the real way" to read decimal fractions. I noticed in particular how you put spaces between the digits in places where you will almost never see spaces in a decimal fraction with eight digits after the decimal point in any mathematical, scientific, or engineering text. "Hundred millionths" is also a problematic expression in practice; it can easily be misunderstood to mean $100/1000000$ rather than $1/100000000.$

Comment: @DavidK thanks for the input, better than someone saying it's stupid, or responses from people who may have just forgot what they were taught early on in life. So I definitely reworded in what aspect my response was for.

Comment: @Edward That was a good revision of the answer.